# How to solve $(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

Tags: c

I am learning C language and I tried a simple program using scanf() which keeps giving me an error. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int area;//global variable
int main ()
{
int a, b;//local variables

/*actual initialization*/
printf("enter the value of side a:");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("enter the value of side b:");
scan("%d", &b);
printf("\n");
printf("\t you have entered %d for side a 
and %d for side b\n",a,b);

area=a*b;
printf("\t the area of your rectangle is 
:%d \n",area);

return 0;
}
```

This is part of the output I get:

```
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev- 
Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev- 
Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/4.8.1/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev- 
Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/4.8.1/include" -I"C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
BIN      = "c+ flo project.exe"
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean 
clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

Untitled6.o: Untitled6.c
$(CC) -c Untitled6.c -o Untitled6.o 
$(CFLAGS)
```

From what I have been reading around I learnt its a linker error but I dont know how to fix it. I use Dev C++. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

This isn't the error message. It's the command that links your program. Or rather, mostly variables that will be expanded to the right linker command. For instance, `$(CC)` will turn into the name of your compiler (which is also doing the linking), `$(LINKOBJ)` will be the object file resulting from compiling `Untitled6.c`, which presumably is the file that holds the code of your program.

You didn't post your error message, but when I try to run your program, I get an error here:

```
scan("%d", &b);
```

This is likely a typo and you meant `scanf` instead of `scan`. Also, those prints

```
printf("\t you have entered %d for side a 
and %d for side b\n",a,b);
```

Don't work because that line break is breaking the string literal. It should all be on one line (or you can put a `\` at the end of a line to make the compiler "ignore" the line break, but I wouldn't recommend that for now). But I assume that this is just the result of pasting the code here and that it's correct in your program anyway.

Since you didn't find your error message (but a lot of other interesting output), try if you can find the actual error message in Dev C++ so you know where to look for the next time you have an error. For me, the error message was `identifier "scan" is undefined`, it's probably going to be something similar for you.

Comment: Thanks, this was an eye opener.